# How to upgrade bazel?

Tags: bazel, failed-installation

I built bazel-0.4.0 successfully.
Then I tried upgrading it to the latest version **bazel-0.5.1** using

```
$ ./compile.sh compile ../bazel-0.4.0/output/bazel.exe
```

It's giving me an error, **bazel-0.5.0**, **bazel-0.4.5** gave me same error

ERROR LOG:

```
$ ./compile.sh compile ../bazel-0.4.0/output/bazel.exe  
 Building Bazel with Bazel.  
ERROR: Illegal javabase value 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk', javabase must be an absolute path or label.  
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.246s  
ERROR: Could not build Bazel
```

**bazel-0.4.4 gave me different error**

ERROR LOG:

```
 Building Bazel with Bazel.  
.ERROR: no such target '//:Files/Java/jdk': target 'Files/Java/jdk' not declared in package '' defined by C:/Users/potlapel/Downloads/bazel-0.4.4/BUILD.  
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.182s  
ERROR: Could not build Bazel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have bazel installed, you can upgrade by running `bazel build //src:bazel` on a fresh clone of the [git repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel). Or just download [distribution archive](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) and run `./compile`. Details: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install-compile-source.html.

Now I'm not sure you can build bazel 0.5.0 with bazel 0.4.0, there were some incompatible changes around 0.4.3. We test building bazel from scratch, and building bazel with last released bazel, but not building bazel with old releases. That will be supported only after we reach 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bazelisk wrapper to easily change the version of Bazel that the bazel command points to. By default bazelisk will fetch the latest release version, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what mhlopko wrote, you generally don't need to build bazel yourself.  Feel free to download the [binary installer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) and just use that.

Answer (score 0):

- **To install latest bazel**: just run `"brew upgrade bazel"`
- **Problem I had:**
  I wanted 0.5.4 version of bazel for tensorflow 0.8.
- **Failed attempt to install specific version:** `brew install bazel@0.5.1`
- **Final approach that worked to setup specific version of bazel**:

  > 1. Download bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh from  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases location
  > 2. chmod +x ./bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
  > 3. ./bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh

That's it!! check `bazel version` in your terminal. It should give 0.5.4

This approach works for any version of bazel that you want to install..`brew` way to install specific version didnt work for me. Hope this saves you from wasting hours trying alternative ways to set this up!

Comment: `brew` is not a Windows package manager - the original OP is clearly calling `bazel.exe`. I'd also argue that `brew` is not an appropriate package manager for development requirements on any platform, especially where idempotent builds are called for.