# bazel installation to version 0.5.4 or higher to build TensorFlow

Tags: docker, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving, docker-container

I'm building a container for TensorFlow with Bazel using `docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f Dockerfile.devel .` and running it `docker run -it $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel`  as instructed here: https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker

However after when running the `./configure` command I get this error

```sh
root@4489fe3513fc:/serving/tensorflow# ./configure
Extracting Bazel installation...
You have bazel 0.5.1 installed.
Please upgrade your bazel installation to version 0.5.4 or higher to build TensorFlow!
Configuration finished
root@4489fe3513fc:/serving/tensorflow# cd ..
root@4489fe3513fc:/serving# bazel test tensorflow_serving/...
................
ERROR: /serving/WORKSPACE:23:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/serving/WORKSPACE", line 23
                tf_serving_workspace()
        File "/serving/tensorflow_serving/workspace.bzl", line 16, in tf_serving_workspace
                tf_workspace(path_prefix = "", tf_repo_name = "...")
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl", line 146, in tf_workspace
                check_version("0.5.4")
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/f8d1071c69ea316497c31e40fe01608c/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl", line 56, in check_version
                fail("\nCurrent Bazel version is {}, ...))

Current Bazel version is 0.5.1, expected at least 0.5.4
```

Trying to update bazel just gives me the same version number 0.5.1. I'm not sure on how to approach this. Is there a docker supported tag that I'm missing when I try to update?

Comment: What platform are you on? How did you install Bazel -- did you download an installer (`.sh` file) from Bazel's Github page, did you use package manager, or did you build from source?

Comment: @László The Platform is on Windows 10. The Bazel installation is being pulled from (https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel)  which has the bazel setup within it.

Comment: Thanks! When you wrote "Trying to update bazel just gives me the same version number 0.5.1." -- did you mean you edited the Dockerfile and still got 0.5.1? In that case I believe this is not a Bazel bug. I also can't help with Docker though :(

Comment: Looks like this should have been fixed in https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/commit/3f1bfb1675e82c00c326024ffe3db3dc2b25e10f. Hopefully the development docker image has been updated by now?

Answer (score 1):

Even I wanted 0.5.4 version of bazel for tensorflow 0.8.
Tried  `brew install bazel@0.5.1`. Didnt work..

So, I downloaded bazel 0.5.4 version from bazel git release and installed it as follows:

- Download bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh from
  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases
- chmod +x bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
- ./bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
- `bazel version` in your terminal should give 0.5.4

Took barely couple of minutes to install it this way :) Hope that helps!!

(I shared similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775709/how-to-upgrade-bazel/49473359#49473359))